# My query takes years to count + group by

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a website with cities and classifieds in cities. Each classified have at least 1 category.

Here is the schema (with only fields we need here) :

```
Table tv_classified :
id (INT, PK)
village_id (INT) (ID of the classified city)

Table tv_classified_category :
id (INT, PK) (ID of the category)
classified_id (INT, PK) (Foreign key to tv_classified table)
```

I'm trying to get the total of classifieds for each categories in each cities. Something quite basic I guess, but sadly **my query takes years** (and I'm not joking, it's still running after 10 minutes with only 100K rows in tv_classified table).

Here is my query, am I missing something ?

```
SELECT COUNT(*), c.village_id, cat.id as category
FROM tv_classified c
JOIN tv_classified_category cat
GROUP BY c.village_id, cat.id;
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't specify a `join` condition, a cross-join would be performed on the tables. so the number of rows in the result set would be 100K * rows in the other table.

Specify a `join` condition and the query should be fine.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), c.village_id, cat.id as category
FROM tv_classified c
JOIN tv_classified_category cat on cat.classified_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.village_id, cat.id;
```

Comment: OK I'm totally retarded, how could I miss that... It was a long day! Thank you, I'll accept your answer as soon as I can :)